# Mean and standard deviation comparisons

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

[image]I have  datasets (one 1997-2001, another 2020, 2021) with means and standard deviations that I need to compare. Two different dats information (mass and total number). It is expected that I compare the two data sets using statistical analyses.

A t-test was suggested. However I am unsure how to go about this when there are no original data  on the individuals themselves for 2001 data set (only have full original data for 2021). I was able to do a manual hypothesis testing using the two means and standard deviations.
I cannot think of any statistical analyses to represent an appropriate comparison without the original  data from the 2001 data set. I really would appreciate any kind of help or recommendations.

Comment: t tests depend only on means, SDs and sample sizes; Otherwise you can plot say means and confidence intervals.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on what Nick Cox wrote, your situation is you have two populations (1997-2001 vs 2020-2021) with (probably) different variances, and you want to check whether they have the same mean. That's the situation where you would use Welch's t-test.

You have all the numbers to plug into the first formula on the Wikipedia page for Welch's t- test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

The thing to be careful of is that with a t-test you're assuming the means are normally distributed. That's not an issue for the 1997-2001 data since the sample size is quite large. For the 2020-2021 data, you'll want to check for normality by looking at the Q-Q plot and seeing if it looks like a straight line.

Comment: (+1) There is an important detail to flag. As not all birds are found to contain plastic, the mean plastic content is a mean over several zeros  and several positive weights. That bimodal distribution is going to be a little awkward as underlying the sampling distribution of the mean. You could do simulations on the conditional distribution or use bootstrapping to get a handle on the consequences.

Comment: You guys have no idea how thankful I am for your input! Your suggestions helped me big time. Thank you both so much :)